# HDDをマスター・ブート・レコードでフォーマットできない

Tags: macos

先日新しく外付け用の3TBのHDDを買いました。
Windowsも時々使うので両方から読み書きできるようにマスター・ブート・レコード（以下MBR）のexFATでフォーマットする予定でしたが、図のようにグレーになりなぜか選択できませんでした。
3TBの容量が関係してそうですが、何が原因なのか分かりません。
分かる方がいらっしゃいましたら、原因と解決策を教えていただけたら幸いです。
ご力添え、よろしくお願いします。

追記：GPTのexFATでフォーマットしたHDDはWindowsで認識されませんでした。
追記：Windows：Windows 7 Home Service Pack 1, 64bit。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

MBRは、HDDの記録単位であるセクタを扱える数に制限があり、その数は最大で2の32乗(4,294,967,296)個です。1セクタが512バイトである場合は最大2,199,023,255,552バイト、つまり約2.199TBが限界です。よってそれ以上の容量を持ったHDDをフォーマットする場合には、GPTを使うしかありません。

近年はセクタサイズを4KBにしたHDDがありますが、OSで認識するセクタサイズが512byteの場合、上記の制限に当たります。

WindowsでGPTを使うには、使用しているOSのバージョンの対応状況に注意が必要です。Windows 7や8の**64bit版**といった最近のOSであれば認識すると思います。

Comment: 早速のご返信有難うございます。
GPTのexFATでフォーマットしたHDDをWindowsに接続してみましたが、認識されませんでした。
ちなみに、Windowsのシステムは Windows 7 Home ServicePack 1, 64bit です。

Comment: ブートに利用するのではなく、データ用としての利用でよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: はい。データ用です。
ただいまUSBケーブルを変えてみましたら認識されるようになりました。
ケーブルの問題？なのか分かりませんが、なんだか釈然としない気分ですね。。。
ともかく色々ありがとうございました。

Comment: 検証してみたらUSBポートの問題みたいです。片側だけ認識してくれないですね。

Comment: 認識しなかったUSBポートに他の機器を挿してみることで、HDDをUSB接続した時だけ問題が発生するのかUSBポートの不良なのか原因を切り分けできます。

Comment: @pixy 自己解決した場合には自身で回答を書き込んで、チェックして頂ければ他の回答者に参考になると思います。よろしくお願いします。